# Can I retract my 'approved suggested edit' vote?

Tags: support

Today, while I was reviewing Suggested Edits, I approved one I wanted to reject. The Edit needed another vote in order to be approved, but is there any way I retract my vote ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can keep an eye on it and revert if it is approved, if it's bad enough to warrant that.